# Why RSA uses {d,n} as private key instead of {e,n}?

Tags: rsa

While studying the RSA algorithm I referred to some books and some sites such as [RSA (wikipedia)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RSA_%28algorithm%29#Key_generation) and all of them chose **{d,n} as the secret (private) key** and release **{e,n} as the public key** but as **d** and **e** are multiplicative inverse of each other, can't we keep **{e,n} as private key** and use the other as public key? Is it a standard rule to choose the {d,n} as the private key?

Comment: If $d$ is small, then there is an attack called Wiener's attack - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wiener%27s_attack So $d$ should not be small

Comment: @kelalaka Yes this is exactly what I want to know, thanks!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The letters *d* and *e* are just a notation -- what matters is that there are two exponents, each undoing what the other does, and making one public does not intrinsically reveal the other. **By tradition**, the one made public is called *e*.

*However*, there is a twist: the exponent that is *not* made public, i.e. the private key, can be really private only if it is sufficiently big. If the private exponent is very small (e.g. it fits on 20 bits), then it is easy to rebuild it from the public key, if only by trying all possibilities. If the private exponent is not so small but still substantially smaller than the modulus *n*, more advanced attacks are possible, to the same effect (there is an attack by Coppersmith which works as long as the private exponent length is no more than 29% of the length of *n*).

Conversely, there is no issue in the *public* exponent being small. That exponent can be as small as the value 3, although, there again by tradition (and also out of a solid dose of historical confusion), 65537 is often used as public exponent. Small exponents promote faster computations. Since the public exponent can be small, we thus make them *very* small.

So if you generate your key pair and choose both exponents as big numbers (more or less the same size as *n*), then you can choose either one to be the public exponent (which will be thereafter called *e*). However, if you selected one of the exponents to be small, then the small exponent shall be the public one, because otherwise your key would be very weak and prone to cracking.

Some widespread implementations of RSA don't tolerate big public exponents; e.g. the one in Windows CryptoAPI, used by Internet Explorer when doing SSL, requires the public exponent to fit on 32 bits.

Comment: It is important to ensure that the greatest common divisor between `(p-1)(q-1)` and `e` is equal to 1, however. You cannot simply choose `65537` to be the public exponent unless you are checking this condition.

Comment: @Brendon 65537 is prime so that condition is just doing a modulo of (p-1)%65537 and (q-1)%65537 if either is equal to 0 then you need to choose a different p or q (depending on which was 0)

Comment: @Brendon: it normally goes the other way round. _e_ is chosen first, then _p_ and _q_ are selected such that _p-1_ and _q-1_ are both coprime to _e_. That's how many (most ?) RSA key generation engines work.

Answer (score 5):

Note: This answer was written for the [question *"In RSA, are $e$ and $d$ technically equivalent?"*](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/264808), that was migrated from security-SE, then merged here. The relevant parts of that other question are quoted.

> In the process of finding RSA key pairs, we first find a $e$ that is relatively prime to $\varphi(n)$ (where $n = p \times q$), and then find $d$ such that $e \times d \bmod \varphi(n) = 1$.

I'll be taking this as an assumption†, with additionally $p$ and $q$ distinct‡, large, random, independently chosen, and of course secret primes.

> Is $d$ also relatively prime to $\varphi(n)$, or not necessarily?

**Necessarily**. That follows from $e \times d \bmod \varphi(n) = 1$.

> If we choose $e$ to be a large enough number, can $e$ and $d$ be used interchangeably?

**TL;DR: Don't do it**.

Full version: **Yes, but** if we want RSA to be secure only if all the following applies:

- That *large enough number* truly is. Less than $n^{0.292}$ is known too small (see [this](https://doi.org/10.1007/3-540-48910-X_1)). Attacks only get better, thus it seems advisable $e>2^{\left\lceil\log_2(\max(p,q))\right\rceil}$; and I known no proof that's enough.
- The choice of $e$ (now used as a private exponent) is random, and in particular $e$ is not chosen according to $\varphi(n)$, $p$, or $q$, beyond ensuring that $e$ is relatively prime to $\varphi(n)$, or to both $p-1$ and $q-1$; and perhaps $e<p\cdot q$ or something on that tune.
- And of course, $e$ (now used as a private exponent) remains secret.

And **further, in practice**, if all the following applies:

- In use of the key, nothing enforces a small maximum value on the public exponent (now $d$, which will be large). There's often such limit, e.g. $<2^{32}$ in some ancient Windows crypto API, or $<2^{256}$ ([FIPS 186-4](https://nvlpubs.nist.gov/nistpubs/FIPS/NIST.FIPS.186-4.pdf#%5B%7B%22num%22%3A127%2C%22gen%22%3A0%7D%2C%7B%22name%22%3A%22XYZ%22%7D%2C70%2C191%2C0%5D)). Such small limit makes exchanging $d$ and $e$ incompatible with security.
- An upper limit is set for $e$ (now used as private exponent) that is compatible with libraries/devices used, which typically enforce a limit $<n$ ([PKCS#1](https://pkcs1.grieu.fr/#page=6)), sometime $<\varphi(n)$, or $<\lambda(n)$ with $\lambda(n)=\operatorname{lcm}(p-1,q-1)$ ([FIPS 186-4](https://nvlpubs.nist.gov/nistpubs/FIPS/NIST.FIPS.186-4.pdf#%5B%7B%22num%22%3A127%2C%22gen%22%3A0%7D%2C%7B%22name%22%3A%22XYZ%22%7D%2C70%2C191%2C0%5D)).
- We don't care about encryption and signature verification performance: because the public exponent (now $d$) will be large, cost of the textbook RSA public key operation will skyrocket from $17$ modular multiplications for the usual $e=65537$, to in the order of $1.5$ time the bit length of $n$. That's possibly well over a hundred times slower for 2048-bit $n$. The two most common reasons to use RSA nowadays are the speed and simplicity of RSA signature verification compared to ECC; but swapping $e$ and $d$ turns the noticeable speed advantage into a noticeable speed disadvantage.

---

† Common practice in actual use of RSA is to first select a small odd $e\ge3$, often a prime, very often $e=2^{(2^4)}+1=65537$, *then* generate random primes $p$ and $q$ with $\gcd(p-1,e)=1$ and $\gcd(q-1,e)=1$; then, when it's desired to compute $d$ (indispensable only to export/store the private key in an interoperable way), a modern trend (and/due to a requirement in [FIPS 186-4](https://nvlpubs.nist.gov/nistpubs/FIPS/NIST.FIPS.186-4.pdf#%5B%7B%22num%22%3A127%2C%22gen%22%3A0%7D%2C%7B%22name%22%3A%22XYZ%22%7D%2C70%2C191%2C0%5D)) is to use $d=e^{-1}\bmod\lambda(n)$, where $\lambda(n)=\operatorname{lcm}(p-1,q-1)$.

‡ $p\ne q$ is mathematically required to make $x\mapsto x^e\bmod n$ a permutation of $[0,n)$, and to have $\varphi(n)=(p-1)\times(q-1)$, and to make $n$ hard to factor. In practice, $p$ and $q$ being large, random, and independently chosen almost certainly implies $p\ne q$.

Comment: It's possible to extend this to protocols and API's. The pubic exponent is often stored with the private exponent, CRT parameters are only present for the private key, side channel protection may be missing for the public key operations etc. TBH, any use of the public exponent as "secret" would count as an immediate vulnerability in my book.

Comment: I told others *d* and *e* are "technically equivalent" and I just want to make sure that I am correct. You answer is more than I expected, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

There's nothing special about `e` -- it's simply a number you select so that `e` and `(p-1)(q-1)` are coprime. In general, `e` will be a small prime, e.g. 7 or 65537 (as per Wikipedia page). `d` is the multiplication inverse of `e` ***modulo*** (p-1)(q-1). This does not mean that `d` is simply equal to `1/e` -- it is very difficult to obtain `d` from `e` unless you also have `(p-1)(q-1)`.

In essence, `e` is just a degree of freedom in the algorithm -- the reason for the flexibility is because `e` and `(p-1)(q-1)` will need to be coprime, which may not hold for every choice of `e`. So the public key is really just `n` and the decryption key is just `{d,n}`.

Just to use some numbers, suppose we chose the primes:

- `p = 67706614564338235002765566951242539340333032205026461307043629937913994975109`
- `q = 90947554097423668858730894787242356004957551116627660855305597239344082875989`

Then `N=p*q=6157750990843564899040526104103265719297860652172632823400065455699068450255812459659898039342299176739625908677540037844125877114187853026418999188757801`

Taking `e=29` ensures that `gcd((p-1)(q-1), e) = 1`. We can use Euclid's algorithm to determine

- `d=2972707374889996847812667774394680002419656866566098604400031599302998562192384595754389927039245776685876687343128498677629624892701967351358081915610133`.

Just looking at the length of `d` compard to `e`, I hope, is enough to convince you why keeping `d` secret is the important.

For encryption, the calculation is `M^e mod N`, where `M` is your plaintext message. For decryption, it is `E^d mod N`, where E is your encrypted message.

Comment: yes, you are right but what if both are equivalent in length?

Comment: If the public exponent is selected uniformly from $\mathbb Z_{\phi((p-1)(q-1))}^*$, it doesn't matter which exponent you call $e$ and which you call $d$, just as long you keep the private one consistently private.